# Am I missing any kernel files? If so, which ones and how should I install them?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm not certain if I'm missing files for Linux kernel 3.11, nor how to install any missing files.

When I type:

```
me@Bedrock1:~$ uname -r
3.11.0-23-generic
```

which makes me believe I'm running kernel 3.11. However, I'm unable to install NVIDIA graphics card drivers. When I attempt to install with

```
me@Bedrock1:~$ sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I get (in part) the following output:

```
Loading new nvidia-340-340.58 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.11.0-23-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

I read this as meaning it checked to see which kernels I had (I can have more than 1 ????) and then tried to install the divers for kernel 3.11, but couldn't because the kernel "does not seem to be installed !?

I, next, used dpkg to see which Linux files I had installed and saw this:

```
me@Bedrock1:~/Downloads/cudaDownloads$ dpkg -l | grep "linux-" | cut -d " " -f 3
gcc-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu-base
linux-firmware
linux-headers-3.13.0-29
linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-30
linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-32
linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-34
linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-35
linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-36
linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-37
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-39
linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-3.11.0-23-generic
linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-23-generic
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-33-generic
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-sound-base
linux-source
linux-source-3.13.0
syslinux-common
syslinux-legacy
```

So, it appears as though I have image files for kernels 3.11 & 3.8, header files for 3.13 & source files for 3.13.

When I look at my boot directory, I see:

```
me@Bedrock1:~$ ls /boot
abi-3.11.0-23-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.8.0-33-generic          memtest86+.elf
config-3.11.0-23-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.8.0-33-generic       System.map-3.11.0-23-generic
grub                          System.map-3.8.0-33-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-23-generic  vmlinuz-3.11.0-23-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-33-generic   vmlinuz-3.8.0-33-generic
```

So, again it looks as though I'm running kernel 3.11 (and could possibly run kernel 3.8?)

I don't really know anything about linux kernels, but I suspect in order to install the NVIDIA driver, I need to install linux-headers-3.11 and linux-source-3.11. Am I correct in this? If so, how do I install them and what do I need to beware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you need to install Linux headers.
In your case it should be linux-headers-3.11.0-23-generic.
According to the list you provided you did not install it.

You can download the appropriate .deb file and install it with dpkg -i linux-headers-3.11.0-23-generic.deb

And as a side-note: Yes, you can have multiple kernel at the same time.
At boot time you'll be presented a menu to choose which kernel you want to start.
It is good practice to keep always at least 2 kernels just in case something goes wrong with one of the kernels. In case of trouble then you can use the second kernel to boot the computer.

Comment: @wieOoma Will there be any unexpected consequences? If these were regular header files, I wouldn't think so, but I really don't know about how kernels & their installations work. Specifically, I (somehow) got a bunch of 3.13 headers installed. Could adding the 3.11 headers cause any confusion elsewhere on my machine?

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no consequences. Adding additional headers does not cause problems. Headers are used in the building process of modules/drivers etc. Therefore you get the complaint about missing files. Any other header version is apparently not used.